# How do I share Y axes magnitude with many subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a CSV that contains three columns: `DATE,LOC,CNT` (sample is below). I want a lot of subplots (eventually there will be about 200) made out of this (I'm thinking sparkline sized plots, but I'm not that far yet). The problem I am having is that my plots aren't sharing a Y axes magnitude, so groups that have vastly different counts look similar.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfh = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
num_sites = dfh['LOC'].nunique()

cols = 5
rows = int(math.ceil(float(num_sites) / cols))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols)

grouped = dfh.groupby('LOC')

targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
    ax.plot(grouped.get_group(key)['CNT'])

plt.show()
```

Sample data:

```
DATE,LOC,CNT
2017-06-01,Loc 1,1
2017-06-02,Loc 1,6
2017-06-03,Loc 1,4
2017-06-04,Loc 1,1
2017-06-05,Loc 1,1
2017-06-01,Loc 2,0
2017-06-02,Loc 2,7
2017-06-03,Loc 2,4
2017-06-04,Loc 2,10
2017-06-05,Loc 2,12
2017-06-01,Loc 3,5
2017-06-02,Loc 3,2
2017-06-03,Loc 3,1
2017-06-04,Loc 3,8
2017-06-05,Loc 3,1
2017-06-01,Loc 4,19
2017-06-02,Loc 4,20
2017-06-03,Loc 4,15
2017-06-04,Loc 4,12
2017-06-05,Loc 4,22
2017-06-01,Loc 5,0
2017-06-02,Loc 5,1
2017-06-03,Loc 5,1
2017-06-04,Loc 5,2
2017-06-05,Loc 5,2
2017-06-01,Loc 6,7
2017-06-02,Loc 6,5
2017-06-03,Loc 6,7
2017-06-04,Loc 6,5
2017-06-05,Loc 6,6
```

This is producing:

[image: Sample Output]

Notice that I have plots that have a max Y of 7, 2, 22, 8, 12 6 and then a few blank plots with a max of 1.

---

My question: How can I make each of these plots share the same Y axes? The X axes should be the same too, but I think that is just going to involve me removing the X axes label, since I've confirmed in the data that each group has the same X points.

Bonus: Is there a way to remove those few empty plots at the end? I can't guarantee that I'll have a set of plots that fills an entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share all yaxes, use

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, sharey=True)
```

same for x: `sharex=True`.

To remove the superfluous axes you could turn them off by appending

```
for j in range(i+1, len(axs.flatten())):
    axs.flatten()[j].axis("off")
```

where `i` is the loop variable from the previous loop.

A complete working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfh = pd.DataFrame({"LOC" : np.random.randint(0,6, size=100),
              "CNT" : np.arange(100)})

cols = 5
rows = 2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, sharey=True, sharex=True)

grouped = dfh.groupby('LOC')

targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
    ax.plot(grouped.get_group(key)['CNT'])

for j in range(i+1, len(axs.flatten())):
    axs.flatten()[j].axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding that last code block to turn off the axes. I put that for loop after my `ax.plot()` line, but it produces this: https://i.imgur.com/v1DTSyk.png  Setting `sharey` works though. Thank you!

Comment: It's always the same: People ask a question without reproducible code but then complain about the answers not showing reproducible code. I have included a [mcve] now.